# Setting argv[0] to longer value than currently allocated

Tags: c, argv

I am writing a program in C that spawns loads of processes and that should report their state via argv[0] so while calling `ps` it's easy to see what's going on.

I am aware that initially argv[0] comes with certain memory allocated, that contains the program name (in most cases).

I need however to set much longer string than 20 bytes that contain my program name. My status can be 80-100 characters long.

I made some tests and if I memcpy this longer string into argv[0] it "works for me" but I am afraid that I will start writing into unowned memory and cause segfault which is unacceptable.

How can I safely resize memory allocated for argv[0]?

Sample code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* generate_really_long_program_name() {
  return strdup("here is something that generates really long program name\0");
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Current argv[0] length: %zu\n", strlen(argv[0]));

  char* my_program_name = generate_really_long_program_name();
  strncpy(argv[0], my_program_name, strlen(my_program_name)); // Can this segfault?
  free(my_program_name);

  printf("New argv[0] length: %zu\n", strlen(argv[0]));

  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./argv
Current argv[0] length: 6
New argv[0] length: 57
```

Comment: As to "can this segfault" - that would be to some degree implementation dependent, but it certainly seems possible. Perhaps more dangerously, you're writing data to a buffer whose "valid" size you don't know - thus, you're very likely to be overwriting data, the consequences of which are unknown-but-probably-bad. Best of luck.

Comment: *My status can be 80-100 characters long.*  Don't use a hack like this to pass status unless non-portability and unreliability are actual goals.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't care about portability, the target environment is fixed. Reliability is a must, that's a reason why I ask for help.

Comment: @mspanc You don't care about portability, but what about update of your system ?

Answer (score 1):

To change name display in `ps` under Linux, use [`prctl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) instead of changing `argv[0]` (which is a hack - and this hack doesn't work on everywhere):

```
int s;
s = prctl(PR_SET_NAME,"myProcess\0",NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

After this line execution, take a look at `ps`, you will see "myProcess" instead of original name.

You are free to pass any string you want to `prctl`, regardless original length of `argv[0]`. But if your string is more than 16 bytes (including terminating null byte, it will be truncated:

> **PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)**
>                 Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the
>                 location pointed to by (char *) arg2.  The name can be up to
>                 16 bytes long, including the terminating null byte.  (If the
>                 length of the string, including the terminating null byte,
>                 exceeds 16 bytes, the string is silently truncated.)  This is
>                 the same attribute that can be set via pthread_setname_np(3)
>                 and retrieved using pthread_getname_np(3).  The attribute is
>                 likewise accessible via /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm, where tid
>                 is the name of the calling thread.

---

For your question about this:

```
strncpy(argv[0], my_program_name, strlen(my_program_name)); // Can this segfault?
```

C99 standard says:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

but you can't increase size of `argv[0]`, so you will get an undefined behavior if `strlen(my_program_name)` is greater than already allocated memory for `argv[0]`: buffer overflow, segfault or anything else because it's UB

Comment: `prctl` is not a solution for me as it is limited to 16 bytes. I intentionally want to modify argv[0].

Comment: @mspanc I don't know about your system, but on my Ubuntu 14.04, program names are truncated to 16 bytes, and I guess `ps` is developed according this limitation. Also, always on my system, modifying `argv[0]` doesn't change anything on `ps`