# Program segfaults when run outside its own directory

Tags: c, linux

I have *almost* successfully modified a publicly available program. If I run it from its own directory, it works fine:

```
$ pwd
/Users/elisabete/Project/temperley-keyb/keyb
$ ./key ../test/example.noteb 
Cm Cm
```

But if I change the directory (no matter to what directory), I get a segmentation fault error:

```
$ cd ..
$ keyb/key test/example.noteb 
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
```

Using the full path to the executable apparently has no influence:

```
$ pwd
/Users/elisabete/Project/temperley-keyb/keyb
$ /Users/elisabete/Project/temperley-keyb/keyb/key ../test/example.noteb 
Cm Cm
$ cd ..
$ /Users/elisabete/Project/temperley-keyb/keyb/key test/example.noteb 
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
```

The program code in itself is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int z=0, b=0, c=0, s=0, j, line_no=0, i, pitch, tpc_found, npc_found, seg_beat=-1, optc=0, opterr=0;
  char *parameter_file = NULL, *input_file = NULL;
  int param_file_specified = 0;

  while ((optc = getopt (argc, argv, "p:s:")) != -1)
    switch (optc) {
      case 'p':
        parameter_file = optarg;
        param_file_specified = 1;
        break;
      case 's':
         sscanf(optarg, "%d", &seg_beat);;
         break;
      case '?':
         if (optopt == 'p')
           fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        if (optopt == 's')
             fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
         else if (isprint (optopt))
           fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
         else
           fprintf (stderr,
                "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
         return 1;
       default:
         abort ();
       }

  for (j = optind; j < argc; j++)
     input_file = argv[j];

  /* Codes goes on */
```

Running it with `gdb` gave the following result, but I can't make nothing of it:

```
$ gdb -q keyb/key
Reading symbols from keyb/key...Reading symbols from /Users/elisabete/Project/temperley/source/keyb/key.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/key...done.
done.
(gdb) run ../test/extract2.noteb 
Starting program: /Users/elisabete/Project/temperley/source/keyb/key ../test/extract2.noteb
[New Thread 0x2503 of process 473]
warning: unhandled dyld version (15)

Thread 2 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff6afe2ea9 in ?? ()
```

I've read what @mspanc said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321583/setting-argv0-to-longer-value-than-currently-allocated), that "initially argv[0] comes with certain memory allocated, that contains the program name (in most cases)," but I suspect this is not related to my problem since using the full path in the program's directory, as well as changing the program to a longer name, doesn't makes it to segfault.

I've already read a lot of posts here in StackOverflow, but couldn't find anything that helped with this particular problem, so any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** Thanks to @lxop 's suggestion, I found the source of the problem. The main() calls a function to read a parameter file that is stored in the source directory, so when I run the program from any other directory it didn't find the file and segfalted. I then substituted the commented line for a message and an exit call:

```
int read_parameter_file(char *filename, int file_specified) {
  FILE *param_stream;

  if(file_specified) {
    param_stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (param_stream == NULL) {
      printf("Warning: cannot open \"%s\".  Using defaults.\n", filename);
      filename = "parameters";
    }
  }
  else {
    filename = "parameters";
    param_stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(param_stream == NULL) {
      /* filename = "key/parameters"; */
      printf("No valid parameter file found, exiting program.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
/* ... */
}
```

Now at least I can exit the program gracefully, but I still don't know how to handle the question of fixing the path to the default parameter file. Where should I put it? In the Makefile (this code has a very simple Makefile), so that whenever a person installs it the full path to the source can be specified? Or any other better place?

The sources are now available at [this github](https://github.com/ElisabeteCoelho/temperley-keyb/tree/development), the offending function starts at line 64 of main.c. Thanks for all the comments and the help given until now!

Comment: Have you tried to track down where the segfault is occurring? Your use of `gdb` is incorrect: instead just run `gdb keyb/key`, then in the gdb console that appears run `run ../test/extract2.noteb`. I suspect the error is not in the code you have supplied.

Comment: The error is not caused by that part of the program that you show us.  "I have successfully modified ..."  Perhaps not?

Comment: Another way to track down where the error is occurring is to put `printf` statements through the code so you can see how far it gets before it dies

Comment: Why don't you put the source code somewhere (patebin, github..) to ppl download it, make and test.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what is `optarg`?

Comment: @lxop Thanks for the correct usage of gdb. Now I have some output, although I still can't get an error line. I have used the `printf` strategy before but I didn't get anything since I wasn't very systematic, this time I'll try to move it block-to-block to try to catch where it segfaults.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I said "successfully" because the code didn't even compile before... ;) The original author made this program eleven years ago and I suspect he didn't maintain it since then...

Comment: @thekamilz I followed your suggestion, please see my edited post.

Comment: @CodeGorilla `optarg` is a variable of `getopt` that gets the argument passed to an option handled by `optarg`. The description of `getopt` can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt) and a practical example is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt).

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `printf("Warning: cannot open \"%s\".  Using defaults.\n", filename);`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error is exposed via a system function, call: `perror()` as that will output both the text and the reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `if(file_specified) {
    param_stream = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (param_stream == NULL) {
      printf("Warning: cannot open \"%s\".  Using defaults.\n", filename);
      filename = "parameters";`   This fails to pass the modified 'filename` to `fopen()`, so if it goes this execution path, any later access to that file will fail.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for the tips! I already improved the code with your suggestions.